# How to go about trawling through pagination results with PHP/Curl?

Tags: php, curl, pagination

Say for example I wanted grab the results from the first 3 pages in Google. So basically I want the top 30 results. I can go about grabbing the first 10 on page 1, but how do I tell Curl that once page one is done, "click" the second page and so on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just take a closer look at the URLs:

First page:

```
http://www.google.com/search?q=lmgtfy
```

Second page:

```
http://www.google.com/search?q=lmgtfy&start=10
```

Comment: perfect for my example! - but let's say that in any other scenario, the pagination links were obscure and you couldn't increment the value, Is it possible to make Curl "click" onto another page?

Comment: There's no general answer for that, screenscraping is always custom work. In 99.99% of all cases though, there's some URL paramater that is simply increased for every page. Google uses `&start=xx`, others may use `&page=x`, still others `/offset:x/` or whatnot. Just analyse the differences between the first, second and third pages and you'll usually figure it out pretty quickly.